# Getting "No such module 'RxSwift'" with Xcode 8 and Swift 3.0

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, rx-swift

I try to use RxSwift in my project. My podfile looks like below, ↓

[image]

I got this error:

[image]

This is my *Link Binary With Libraries* status:

[image]

I have tried to fix it for over three hours. But the answers on the site don't work for me...

Comment: You are only including the two pods in the target `RxStudyTests`, but not in the regular targets, especially not in the target `RxStudy`  (or even better: all targets)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Replace your Podfile like below:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'RxStudy' do
    use_frameworks!

    pod 'RxSwift'
    pod 'RxCocoa'

    target 'RxStudyTests' do
        #Add pod here if you want the access of pod in Tests target.
        #Example: pod 'RxSwift'
    end

    target 'RxStudyUITests' do
        #Add pod here if you want the access of pod in Tests target.
        #Example: pod 'RxSwift'
    end

end
```

Problem with your Podfile is that you are trying to add the pods in the Tests target and not to actual project target. After changing the file as above install the Pods again and then run the project even if you get "No such module error" because it might happen for the first time.

Answer (score 10):

You are inserting the pods in the tests target, not in the project target.

To solve this problem move the pods to the project target as below:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'RxStudy' do
    # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
    use_frameworks!

    # Pods for ProjectName
    # Insert your pods here
    pod 'RxSwift'
    pod 'RxCocoa'

    target 'RxStudyTests' do
        inherit! :search_paths
        # Pods for testing
    end

    target 'RxStudyUITests' do
        inherit! :search_paths
        # Pods for testing
    end

end
```

Comment: i made a stupid mistake! sorry...

Comment: `inherit! :search_paths` did the trick for me! Thank you!